# Only RemoveNode or ReplaceNode works, but not both at the same time

Tags: c#, roslyn

I first replace a node, then try to remove another but nothing happens, no exception is thrown,

If I do it in opposite order, the opposite happens.

Code:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod2()
    {
        const string import = @"
        // DEBUG: bool          DragFloat2(const char* label, float v[2], float v_speed = 1.0f, float v_min = 0.0f, float v_max = 0.0f, const char* format = ""%.3f"", ImGuiSliderFlags flags = 0)
        public static bool DragFloat2(string label, float[] v, float v_speed = 1.0F, float v_min = 0.0F, float v_max = 0.0F, string format = ""%.3f"", global::imgui.NET.ImGuiSliderFlags flags = 0)
        {
            if (v == null || v.Length != 2)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(""v"", ""The dimensions of the provided array don't match the required size."");
            var ___ret = __Internal.DragFloat2(label, v, v_speed, v_min, v_max, format, flags);
            return ___ret;
        }
";

        var tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(import);

        var root = (tree.GetRoot() as CompilationUnitSyntax)!;

        Console.WriteLine(root.ToString());

        var nodes = root.DescendantNodes().ToArray();

        // find the declaration for the method

        var function = nodes.OfType<LocalFunctionStatementSyntax>().Single();

        // find the number of components for the vector from method name (sucks)

        var match = Regex.Match(function.Identifier.ValueText, @"\d+");
        var count = int.Parse(match.Value);

        // replace the float[] parameter by a ref VectorN

        var para1 = nodes.OfType<ParameterSyntax>().Single(s => s.Type is ArrayTypeSyntax);

        var para2 = Parameter(para1.Identifier)
            .WithModifiers(TokenList(Token(SyntaxKind.RefKeyword)))
            .WithType(IdentifierName($"Vector{count}"))
            .NormalizeWhitespace();

        root = root.ReplaceNode(para1, para2);

        // remove the if block

        var @if = nodes.OfType<IfStatementSyntax>().Single();

        root = root.RemoveNode(@if, SyntaxRemoveOptions.KeepNoTrivia)!;

        Console.WriteLine(root.ToString());
    }
```

Result, input/output:

```
public static bool DragFloat2(string label, float[] v, float v_speed = 1.0F, float v_min = 0.0F, float v_max = 0.0F, string format = "%.3f", global::imgui.NET.ImGuiSliderFlags flags = 0)
        {
            if (v == null || v.Length != 2)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("v", "The dimensions of the provided array don't match the required size.");
            var ___ret = __Internal.DragFloat2(label, v, v_speed, v_min, v_max, format, flags);
            return ___ret;
        }

public static bool DragFloat2(string label, ref Vector2 v, float v_speed = 1.0F, float v_min = 0.0F, float v_max = 0.0F, string format = "%.3f", global::imgui.NET.ImGuiSliderFlags flags = 0)
        {
            if (v == null || v.Length != 2)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("v", "The dimensions of the provided array don't match the required size.");
            var ___ret = __Internal.DragFloat2(label, v, v_speed, v_min, v_max, format, flags);
            return ___ret;
        }
```

**Question:**

How can I perform both operations without reparsing every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you've done the first operation, the tree you have is now a "new" tree with new nodes with new identities, so when you're trying to replace an if node from the original tree, that's not going to be present anymore. If you were to replace

```
var @if = nodes.OfType<IfStatementSyntax>().Single();
```

with

```
var @if = root.OfType<IfStatementSyntax>().Single();
```

I'd expect that to work.